# CallbackAPI Incorrect response text

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Бот при запросе выдает ошибку, и отвечает на сообщение несколько раз.

Вот код бота:

```
<?php 

if (!isset($_REQUEST)) {
return;
}

$confirmation_token = '******'; 

$token = '************************'; 

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 


switch ($data->type) : 


case 'confirmation': 
echo $confirmation_token; 
break; 


case 'message_new': 
$msgtext = $data->object->message->text;
$user_id = $data->object->message->from_id;

if ($msgtext == "Начать"){

$request_params = array( 
'message' => "Сообщение", 
'user_id' => $user_id, 
'access_token' => $token, 
'v' => '5.103', 
'random_id' => rand(20,2000000000)
); 
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params); 
file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?'. $get_params); 
}
    echo('ok');
    break;

endswitch;
?>
```

Ошибка:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.16.1
Date: Thu, 12 Mar 2020 17:52:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
```

Что не так в моем коде?

Comment: Не вижу никаких ошибок, но у вас сервер не возвращает `ok` в `default` в `switch`.

Comment: А отправить header?

Comment: Прочитай документацию messages.send.

Comment: На версиях 5.103 нужно еще и отправить HTTP 200.0 OK

Comment: header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); и еще и поставить еще ob_start(); до header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
echo('ok');
```

В начале кода еще поставь ob_start();

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ob_start();

function messagesSend($msg)
{
    global $from_id, $config;
    $methods = array(
        'message' => $msg,

        'user_id' => $from_id,

        'access_token' => $config['token'],
        'v' => 5.103
    );

    $methods = http_build_query($methods);
    file_put_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?' . $methods);
}

$config = array(
    'token' => null,
    'confirmation' => null,
    'secret' => null
);

$vkAnswer = file_get_contents('php://input');
$vkAnswer = json_decode($vkAnswer);

switch($vkAnswer->type)
{
    case 'confirmation':
        exit($config['confirmation']);
        break;

    case 'message_new':
        $from_id = $vkAnswer->object->message->from_id;
        $text = $vkAnswer->object->message->text;

        header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
        echo('ok');

        $messages = array(
            'сообщение' => array(
                'message' => 'ответ'
            ),

            'nullmsg' => array(
                'message' => 'не известное сообщение'
            )
        );

        if(isset($messages[$text]))
        {
            messagesSend($messages[$text]['message']);
        }
        else
        {
            messagesSend($messages['nullmsg']['message']);
        }
        break;

    default:
        header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
        echo('ok');
        break;
}
?>
```